# Macbook 2010 not booting after update (black screen)

Tags: macbook

After performing a fresh install of Loki 0.4.1 on my White Macbook 2010, which worked perfectly, I proceeded to update the system from within the App Center itself. When I rebooted, after entering my disk password (it's encrypted), I got stuck on a black screen with the mouse pointer. I can move it and press enter (which sometimes hides the cursor, but ends up showing it again). I can also open a tty (but it closes itself from time to time to show again the black screen with the pointer, almost like if I were stuck on a loop).

I have tried several things after this:

- Download and install elementaryOS 5.0 Beta 2. Black Screen.
- Download and install elementary0S 0.4.1 Works fine.
- Upgrade a fresh 0.4.1 install. Stops working and black screen appears again.

I have no idea of what to do now, so I would really appreciate if someone could walk me through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer.

1. Once eOS is installed and booted (stuck on the black screen), Open a tty (find a way to access your command line, like `ctrl+alt+fn+F1` on a Mac) and login.
2. `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
3. Add the parameter `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`.
4. Save `(ctrl+x)`, run `sudo update-grub`, and `reboot`.

Now it works (not sure what are the implications of setting nouveau.modeset=0 performance wise, if any)