# Black Screen After Boot – On a Macbook White 2010 / GeForce 320M After Updated to Nvidia 340 Drivers — Running Hera

Tags: macbook, black-screen

Tried to give some new life to my old Macbook White Mid 2010 with Elementary:

**1st First install**

- rEFInd is installed
- Elementary Live version runs fine
- Once installed and system updated (apart from video driver), Elementary will eventually, (after around 10-15 mins, freezes the UI, but still move the cursor. Some time it unfreezes itself, throwing me to the login screen again.

I researched and found that it could be related to video drivers. Ended up installing something related to `ppa` on the Terminal. Not sure. I am not this kind of user. It didn't work and I ended with a black screen after the Elementary "E" symbol is gone after boot.

**2nd Install**

So I did a fresh install. Updated everything, got a freeze again. Later with the laptop on, it unfroze, and the the updater shown a nvidia-340 driver. I installed on it. As well as another kernel-something driver.

Now I got a black screen again and I have no idea on what to do. Can't boot press `CTRL+Alt+F1` to access the command line.

I read about something of `nomodeset` on GRUB, but I don't know how to access it. Pressing repeatedly the `E` key on keyboard before Elemtary logo shows up won't do nothing.

Stack Exchange suggested [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16402/macbook-2010-not-booting-after-update-black-screen) as I wrote the title, but I can't access the tty, as nothing is displayed after the "E" logo disappears.

Comment: Pressing e should be done when you see the GRUB with list of kernels to start. See this thread where I explained how to get into the grub config file to modify it. Step by step guide. Try to follow cautiously https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/25200/19988 Of course you must skip some steps. Just enter the single mode, edit the /etc/default/grub and add after splash quiet nomodeset. Save, exit, restart.

Comment: Do not forget about grub2-mkconfig after change in grub config. I provided the exact command in the link I gave you.

Comment: @Sysadmin I will try this, but I can't really access GRUB screen. Seems like there's a way to do the same using rEFInd. Thanks for answering.

Comment: rEFInd single mode gave me the first result in Google: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112456/how-to-enter-single-user-mode-when-refit-is-installed

Answer (score 0):

It took me a few nights of trying out different fixes until I found the working solution at https://askubuntu.com/a/613573/60614